# Перевод кода из pascal в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pascal, python-3.6

Есть код на паскале и необходимо написать код, работающий также на python:

```
var
  a: array[1..10000] of integer; {исходные данные}
  N: integer; {количество элементов последовательности}
  max: integer; {вычисляемое контрольное значение}
  i, j: integer;
begin
  readln(N);
  max := 0;
  for i := 1 to N do read(a[i]);
  for i := 1 to N-1 do
    for j := i+1 to N do
      if (a[i]*a[j] > max) and (a[i]*a[j] mod 14 = 0) then max := a[i] * a[j];
  writeln(max);
end.
```

Попытка сделать такое на питоне не обвенчалась успехом:

```py
a = [] # Исходные данные

N = int(input())
maxvalue = 0
for i in range(1, N = N - 1):
    for j in range(i = i + 1, N):
        if (a[i] * a[j] > maxvalue) and (a[i] * a[j] %14 == 0):
            maxvalue = a[i] * a[j]
print(maxvalue)
```

Comment: Нумерация массивов и списков на Питоне начинается с 0. Это задача из ЕГЭ?

Comment: я решил пока не нагружать программу, поэтому написал от 1 до 100, если вы об этом

Comment: Эта задача не так решается. Массив не нужен.

Comment: может просто обозначить a = []?

Comment: @Эникейщик так вышло xD

Comment: @becouse да, она

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
a = [4,7,3,14,6,3] # Исходные данные

N = len(a)
maxvalue = 0
for i in range(N - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        if (a[i] * a[j] > maxvalue) and (a[i] * a[j] %14 == 0):
            maxvalue = a[i] * a[j]
print(maxvalue)
```

Почти прямой аналог ввода программы  на Паскале:

```python
N = int(input())
a = []
for _ in range(N):
   a.append(int(input()))
```

Как чаще делают в Python: (N я не стал убирать)

```python
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
N = len(a)
```

Comment: Благодарю! Но как сделать с вводом пользователем чисел? Первый ввод кол-во чисел, а остальные - сами числа

Comment: Второй вариант как раз